# angular module namespace usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would to understand the use of angular module more clearly and deeply.
I have a folder of directives where each directive is on separate file.

My first file(first directive)  has a declaration of

```
angular.module("Name",["Dep1","Dep2"]).directive(....)
```

My second file has a declaration of

```
angular.module("Name").directive(.....)
```

My third file has a declaration of

```
angular.module("Name").directive(.....)
```

and so on.

There for my references of files is like this.

```
<script src="FirstFile"></script>
<script src="SecondFile"></script>
<script src="ThirdFile"></script>
```

I have a couple of questions:

1.How can I get rid of angular.module("Name") declaration in every file?

2. why my first declaration have to be angular.module("Name",["Dep1","Dep2"]) with list of dependencies, can I call this file second in row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first file is **declaring** the angular module. When you pass a second parameter to the `angular.module` function, you are declaring it. Without the parameter, you are **referencing** it.

Declare module:

```
angular.module('moduleName', ['dep1', 'dep2'])
```

Reference module:

```
angular.module('moduleName');
```

A module can only been declared **once**.

Once it is declared, you can "attach" controllers and services etc. to it.

As for you second question, it is generally okay and considered good practice to reference the module in the way you do (`angular.module("name")`).

However, if you really don't want to, you can save it to a variable.

```
var myModule = angular.module('name');

myModule.directive('directiveName', ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Typical best practice would would be to create a `module.js` or `app.js` file where you declare your module and any `config()` or `run()` actions

module.js

```
angular
  .module('MyModule', ['dependency1', 'dependecy2'])
```

directive1.js

```
angular
  .module('MyModule')
  .directive('Directive1' directive1Fn)
```

directive2.js

```
angular
  .module('MyModule')
  .directive('Directive2' directive2Fn)
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <div>...</div>
  <script src='angular.js'></script>
  <script src='module.js'></script>
  <script src='directive1.js'></script>
  <script src='directive2.js'></script>
</body>
```

If you do not wish to call `angular.module(...)` inside each declaration you can import the directive functions into your `module.js` and declare them there (but this depends on your toolchain as to how you would go about this) i.e.

```
var d1 = require('./directive1.js')
var d2 = require('./directive2.js')

angular
  .module('MyModule', ['dependency1', 'dependecy2'])
  .directive('Directive1' d1)
  .directive('Directive2' d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AngularJs!

To answer your question:

1. You can always use object notation:

   ```
   var app = angular.module("Name",["Dep1","Dep2"]);
   //now your app has an instance of the angular modudle which you just initialized
   app.directive("Directive1",function(...));
   app.directive("Directive2",function(...));
   ```
2. Your first declartion **will** always have to include the arrays of dependencies. That is the syntax of angular to initialize a module. If you do this again another time, i.e initialize two angular modules with the same name, angular will throw you an error.

Read more on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How can I get rid of angular.module("Name") declaration in every file?

Possible way

```
var SomeNamespace = {};
SomeNamespace.myApp = angular.module("ngApName",[]);
```

In other files

```
SomeNamespace.myApp,directive(..)
```

You can also remove the name-space & create a simple

```
var x = angular.module('ngAppName',[])
```

and use `x`  while creating this directive or controller or a service .

Basically you need to create a global variable.

> why my first declaration have to be
>   angular.module("Name",["Dep1","Dep2"])

This is because you angular in depenedent on other modules.

For example it can be [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) or [bootstrap-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

If your application is not dpenedent on other modules it can be an ampty array

```
angular.module("Name",[]);
```